No registered 'RaggedTensorToTensor' OpKernel for XLA_GPU_JIT devices
In short, I have the problem of getting the following error when running a keras_cv/retina_net based object-detection model:
"No registered 'RaggedTensorToTensor' OpKernel for XLA_GPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node retina_net_label_encoder_1/RaggedToTensor/RaggedTensorToTensor}}"
These are the details:

The environment>>>

In Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL2), I have a miniconda-environment with
python 3.11, tensorflow 2.16.1 , cuda 12.3, cudnn 8.9 installed.
My GPU is correctly detected as calls to
tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
and
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
both list my single GPU.
I also can verify that the currect version of libcudnn is loaded.

The problem>>>

When I run a keras_cv/retina_net based object-detection model in this WSL/miniconda-environment,
I get the following error/stacktrace:
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1712665745.273803   53364 service.cc:145] XLA service 0x7f5bac002670 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
I0000 00:00:1712665745.280784   53364 service.cc:153]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA RTX A6000, Compute Capability 8.6
2024-04-09 14:29:05.902626: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1839] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:580 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph __inference_one_step_on_data_46308[] on XLA_GPU_JIT: RaggedTensorToTensor (No registered 'RaggedTensorToTensor' OpKernel for XLA_GPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node retina_net_label_encoder_1/RaggedToTensor/RaggedTensorToTensor}}){{node retina_net_label_encoder_1/RaggedToTensor/RaggedTensorToTensor}}
The op is created at: 
File "mnt/c/keras_cv/prv_kerascv_object_detection.py", line 663, in <module>
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 325, in fit
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 118, in one_step_on_iterator
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 106, in one_step_on_data
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras_cv/src/models/object_detection/retinanet/retinanet.py", line 468, in train_step
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 60, in train_step
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras_cv/src/models/object_detection/retinanet/retinanet.py", line 408, in compute_loss
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 814, in __call__
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras_cv/src/models/object_detection/retinanet/retinanet_label_encoder.py", line 202, in call
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras_cv/src/backend/scope.py", line 35, in wrapper
File "home/user/miniconda3/envs/tf216_py311_B/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras_cv/src/bounding_box/to_dense.py", line 65, in to_dense

When I run the same code in another WSL/miniconda-environment
with Python 3.9.18, tensorflow 2.14.0, cuda 11.3, cudnn 8.9 installed,
there are no problems.
Any hints for how to find the root of this error
resp. fix this issue are welcome.

I also get this error when running keras_cv object detection from the docker image tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter (under WSL2)

Any luck? I'm getting this error on Google Colab with tf 2.15.0 and python 3.10.

No luck so far, so I currently stick with my working configuration.

It might have something to do with using the right backend, probably JAX. I ended up switching to HuggingFace, so I don't know for sure. (os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "jax")
